# User can't access shared mailbox on desktop client but can using web client

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, shared-mailbox

One of my users is having a problem accessing our shared email folder on their local client. They are using Outlook 2016 on MacOS High Sierra 10.13, logged in as their user of our Office365 account. They can access the shared mailbox when they log in via the web client and none of my other users are experiencing this issue.

This is a recent migration to 365, so I'm still working things out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The information you mentioned "user can access the shared mailbox in web client" indicates that the mailbox or shared folder permission is correct.

On Outlook 2016 for Mac machine, try the following method to add **shared folders**:

1. On the **Tools** menu, click **Accounts**  > **Advanced** > **Delegates**.
2. Add the mailbox under **People I am a delegate for** or Open these additional mailboxes.

If you have **full access** mailbox permission to that **shared mailbox**, we can directly add it with your credentials:

1. On the **Tools** menu, click **Accounts**.
2. Click the **Plus Sign** to add an additional Exchange account.
3. In the E-mail address field, enter the email address of the shared mailbox.
4. When Authentication for setup, enter your own credentials (your email address and your password).